# Package sf, how to define color by category?

Tags: r, r-sf

the Package sf assign color by default, which is great, but how to customize those color, in my case, can I have Pile=black, tracker=red, panel=bleu

```
library(sf)
dataset= data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          id = c("A-27-2", "A-27-2", "A-27-2"),
           x = c(143.4907147, 143.4907125, 143.4907103),
           y = c(-34.755718, -34.755645, -34.7555693),
           status = c("tracker", "Pile", "panel")
)
map <- st_as_sf(dataset, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
plot(map["status"],pch=20,cex=0.4,key.pos=1)
```

edit : second try, I added a column with the colors, is it possible to reference that column, my real dataframe is 70K rows

```
library(sf)
dataset=data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          id = c("A-27-2", "A-27-2", "A-27-2", "A-27-2"),
           x = c(143.4907147, 143.4907125, 143.4907103, 143.4907081),
           y = c(-34.755718, -34.755645, -34.7555693, -34.7554964),
      status = c("tracker", "panel", "panel", "pile"),
       color = c("blue", "yellow", "yellow", "black")
)
map <- st_as_sf(dataset, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
plot(map["status"],pch=20,cex=0.4,key.pos=1,col=map$color)
```

all good now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would like to use `ggplot` for that, since it is more flexible.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = map, aes(color = status)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(panel = "blue", pile = "black", tracker = "red"))
```

If you have to stick to base plot, you would have to provide the colors using a named vector:

```
library(sf)
dataset=data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                   id = c("A-27-2", "A-27-2", "A-27-2", "A-27-2"),
                   x = c(143.4907147, 143.4907125, 143.4907103, 143.4907081),
                   y = c(-34.755718, -34.755645, -34.7555693, -34.7554964),
                   status = c("tracker", "panel", "panel", "pile")
)

dataset$color <- NA
dataset$color[dataset$status == "pile"] <- "black"
dataset$color[dataset$status == "tracker"] <- "red"
dataset$color[dataset$status == "panel"] <- "blue"

map <- st_as_sf(dataset, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
plot(map["status"],pch=20,cex=2,key.pos=1,col=map$color)
legend("bottomright", legend = c("Pile", "panel", "tracker"), 
       fill = c("black", "blue", "red"))
```

Comment: can you please confirm, if the native plot is not supported, geom_sf is very slow, my data is 70k points

Comment: @Mim I added the base plot version

Comment: thanks @loki, I added a column in the data frame and call it color, with the value I want all good, thanks for that, now, I lost the legend :(

Comment: it is not working, I added a column in the dataframe, every status has a different color, can I simply tell plot to use the column color as a reference

Comment: @Min I added a more convenient way to define the colors. Keep in mind to use `col` in base plot.

Comment: Could you provide any information, error message etc.?

Comment: no error message, it does ignore the column color, and generate using it's own colors

Comment: I get the desired output with the code I provided. Did you try to clean your environment and restart your R session. Perhaps any remainings from before are disrupting the correct build

Comment: my apology, the code works, when I tried it with my real data in PowerBI, it does not work and the reason was color was assigned as factor not character, I changed it now and it is working, sorry again